# Exclude 540x960 devices from layout-sw360dp folder

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to exclude 540x960 devices from layout-sw360dp folder?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because I have a quite complex layout, that I have to set size of a view in dp, not using wrap_content and fill_parent. So I can figure out how to force work it on 540x960 screens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to exclude 540x960 devices from layout-sw360dp folder?

No, because resolution alone is meaningless. Whether a 540x960 device will qualify for `-sw360dp` resources -- or any `-swNNNdp` resource set -- depends upon the screen density as well as its resolution.

Comment: so the ugly hack with getting screen density before calling setContentView and setting separate layout for 540x960 screen is only way for me?

Comment: @Geralt_Encore: Since you have not actually explained what your real problem is, I cannot answer that. You are welcome to open another StackOverflow question to explain how you "set size of a view in dp", explain what problems your current approach is having, and seek assistance for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the screen density before calling the setContentView () method in your activity. If it's 540 × 960, you can call another layout file from the res folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific layout for 540x960 screen, the good way is a folder named layout-540x960 (not layout-h960dp-w540dp in other response)

Comment: This approach has been deprecated for years. The fact that it is no longer included in the documentation suggests that support for it either has been withdrawn or could be withdrawn at any point.

Comment: i know, but i try to help....
make a specific layout for one resolution  should never happen. This question is not "logic"